# How can one find a knot with a given Alexander polynomial?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Suppose that I'm given a polynomial $P$ such that $P$ is the Alexander polynomial of some knot.  Is there an algorithm to come up with a projection of a knot $K$ such that $\Delta(K)=P$? Are there articles about this that give a good algorithm?  Thank you.

Comment: Most books on knot theory cover this fundamental question, such as Lickorish's ***Introduction to knot theory***.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you!  Do you happen to know where in Lickorish's book he addresses this?

Comment: @user806050 I don't recall it in Lickorish, but I know Rolfsen's book has it.  See page 171, theorem 5.  It gives a knot using a surgery description, which you could turn into a projection with some work.

Comment: @KyleMiller Thanks!